# Case sql using dates DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I want to get the month and year of the current date/last month depending on the day.

If were on 8th of the month or before, i want to get the last month and year
Otherwise ,I want to get the current month and year.

How do i do that using sql on DB2?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Subtract 8 days and use the `year()` and `month()` functions:

```
select year(current_timestamp - 8 day),
       month(current_timestamp - 8 day)
```